# WPF TabControl, switching to another TabItem does not work, sticks to first TabItem

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tabcontrol, itemssource

I have a control that contains following XAML code. It works fine excepted that I caInnot switch to another TabItem. I read that `TabControl` virtualizes the `TabItem`, I suspect the strange behaviour, namely that I cannot get to display any other TabItem as the first one, is related to this.

```
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate> <!-- header -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Shared="False"> <!-- tabitem content -->
                <controls:ItemControl Item="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

I tried to set the `x:Shared` attribute of the `DataTemplate` to `False` but has not the expected effect. Is there a way to reach this without going the way of using a custom style and replacing the `TabControl` with an `ItemsControl`. I mean the functionality of `TabControl` is what I would like, I would like to simply use it with `ItemsSource` binding...

Comment: What type are you binding to in Items? The virtualization should not effect anything as it only does so for the actual TabItems, not their content.

Comment: It's actually an `ObservableCollection<IItem>` where each `IItem` has a collection of `IAttribute` which are displayed in the custom ItemControl (and works fine, the first IItem is displayed properly + Tabs for all other IItems are present) I just looks like I cannot switch.

Comment: Maybe additionally I migrated from WinForms, previously before using Data Binding I had an intermediate state of the migration where I created programmatically the TabItems and added them to the TabControl. By that time, the TabControl behaved properly. By switching to Binding to the ItemsSource, the situation became weird.

Comment: @MrDosu, if I interpret your question in other words, do you maybe mean I should bind to a collection of Controls instead and not to ModelViews/Models? Maybe that is the way TabControl is intended to be used...

Comment: No you should be binding to viewmodels always. Are you getting the same erronous behaviour if you substitute the IItems collection with something simple and the custom ItemControl with a TextBlock, also? I am having a hard time replicating this here.

Comment: You might also try to skip defining the ContentTemplate of the TabControl and instead use a DataTemplate keyed by type somewhere within resource scope or a DataTemplateSelector on the TabControl. Using a selector also has the nice benefit that you can easily debug whats going on on template selection.

Comment: If I use a simple TextBlock instead of `controls.ItemControl` I have the same issue. Now if I bind to an `IEnumerable<String>` it behaves the way I expect!! Thanks for the hint I need now to reformulate the question as it seems to have to do with what is bound and not how it is done...

Comment: If your IItems override equality operators the tabcontrol could get confused about vitualizing i think, might be worth looking into

Comment: You're a genius, yes it does override Equals and if I try with a simple class that override Equals and let it return always true, I have the same faulty behavior. This hint seems to really good! Let me check with the original class.

Comment: Yes that's it! It was due to a flawed Equals implementation! Please put your hint as an answer, you deserve the points for it. I am struggling since a while on this, I never would have looked for a relationship between an overridden Equals and what I have observed without your hint.

Comment: Stackoverflow is all about learning and helping people, not the points. Having said that: give me my points! ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour will happen if you are binding to a collection that has duplicate objects in it.
Duplication can occur due to having added an object multiple times or because equality has been redefined for the objects in question.

Comment: That's brilliant, it would have taken me ages to figure it out by myself (if I would have found it at all). Rather I would have reverted the whole code to a worse solution without data binding (and nor discovered neither fixed the bug in `Equals`)